# WPF and UWP , compatibility for earlier windows

Tags: wpf, xaml, uwp, windows-runtime

I'm developing an app using WPF , to be used in windows 7x86 up to latest windows 10 versions.
I've been trying to find a way to use UWP APIs in my app, remember I'm building an app in windows 10 to be used in all versions of windows 7 , 8 and 10!
already looked at [this app identity][1] and [these runtime APIs][2] .
specifically looking for sth like this [person picture control][3]
[3]: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/person-picture
[1]: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/publish/view-app-identity-details
[2]: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/desktop/modernize/desktop-to-uwp-supported-api#apis-supported-in-both-converted-apps-and-desktop-applications

and also a way to use fluent xaml theme editor or sth like that!

Answer (score 0):

You're not going to be able to use UWP APIs and remain compatible with Windows 7 or (I'm 99% certain) even Windows 8. Yes, Microsoft has introduced various ways to consume UWP APIs and controls in WPF and even plain old Win32 apps, some more hack-ish than others, but the resulting applications will still require Windows 10 to run.

If you need to stay compatible with Windows 7, you need to use plain vanilla WPF. Sorry! On the bright side, I've yet to find anything groundbreaking in UWP that can't be replicated in WPF satisfactorily.